# What does TCP control bits 0 mean in VPC Flow Logs?

Tags: tcp, amazon-vpc, tcpdump

I know that control bits in tcp define the flags of TCP connection like SYN, FIN, ACK. But from my network traffic sometimes for some packets control bits are 0 (not-set).

What does this behaviour mean?

Comment: I have the same issue. More than that the logs contain a lot of send data.

Answer (score 1):

Those are [flags of a TCP segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure), not connection.

When a flag bit isn't set that indicates the absence of the meaning and behavior defined for the corresponding flag.

Answer (score 0):

It means ACK and only ACK flag is set.  RFC says ACK is 16,  however it's only 16 when used in combination with another flag e.g.  SYN/ACK (18), FIN/ACK (17).  Flags value 0 could also indicate a 'null' scan.

If you see a flow record with value 2 and there are 8 packets in it,  that means there are both SYN packet(s) and ACK packets.

If you see 18 and there are more than 1 packet in the flow that means there is at least one SYN/ACK and the rest are ACK.

Answer (score 0):

AWS answers this in part in their help article ["Logging IP traffic using VPC Flow Logs"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) in the section ["Flow Log Records: Available Fields"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html#flow-logs-fields) (emphasis mine).

> The bitmask value for the following TCP flags:
>
> - FIN — 1
> - SYN — 2
> - RST — 4
> - SYN-ACK — 18
>
> **If no supported flags are recorded, the TCP flag value is 0.**
>
> TCP flags can be OR-ed during the aggregation interval. For short connections, the flags might be set on the same line in the flow log record, for example, 19 for SYN-ACK and FIN, and 3 for SYN and FIN. For an example, see [TCP flag sequence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs-records-examples.html#flow-log-example-tcp-flag).
>
> For general information about TCP flags (such as the meaning of flags like FIN, SYN, and ACK), see [TCP segment structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) on Wikipedia.

In other words, you received a message that was not one of the four expected flags (`FIN`, `SYN`, `RST` or `SYN-ACK`).